# How to cancel ThreadPoolTaskExecutor task

Tags: java, spring

I've submitted a job to `Spring` `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`:

```
  @Autowired
  private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;
  private Map<String,Runnable> runningTasks = new HashMap<>();

  public String doSomeTask() {
    Runnable job = new MyJob();
    String id = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(32);
    taskExecutor.execute(job);
    runningTasks.put(id, job);
    return id;
  }
```

Now I want to cancel some job. I have the runnable object, which has no `interrupt()` method, because threads are managed by executor. But I can't find a method for cancelling a given job on the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

Am I missing something obvious or I've taken the wrong executor implementation?

Comment: You get back a`Future ` object which has a`cancel () ` method. Your task needs to check for the interrupted flag itself though.

Comment: ^^^ you have to use `submit`, not `execute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not even compile this but the idea is very similar daniu and Savior's comment above,

change the map

```
//private Map<String,Runnable> runningTasks = new HashMap<>();
private Map<String,Future<?>> runningTasks = new HashMap<>();
```

use submit to run the task,

```
//taskExecutor.execute(job);
runningTasks.put(id, taskExecutor.submit(job));
```

then when you need to cancel a task, just get it from the map and

```
runningTasks.get(id).cancel(true);
```